# Can I attach to process on remote machine with Visual Studio using Powershell script

Tags: visual-studio, powershell, remote-debugging

I have Visual Studio running on my dev machine. And I have an app running on VM. I want to attach to that app process running on vm from my Visual Studio. I can do it with UI interface provided by VS. But I am looking for an option to do it using PowerShell/VS developer cmd Script. Is there a command to do it? My remote machine has msvsmon running with no auth settings.